# Use linq to load Navigation Property without Declaring Foreign Key

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

The project I'm in is using Entity Framework 6 with code first and has central database and a local database. The central DB is the same as the Local DB with the exception that all relationships (Foreign keys, primary keys etc) have been removed.

So lets imagine that I have the following classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}

public class ProductType
{
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

if the database has a foreign key in the Product table I can do

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = ctx.Produts.Include(x => x.ProductType);
```

If the datbase doesnt have the foreign key, will EF still load the ProductType object using the code above?

Comment: I think you could try to use ICollection and not List<T> -- this is just from memory though, thus just making a comment.

Comment: is it a yes/no question?

Comment: Are just the referential constraints removed in the central db but the columns still exist?

Answer (score 0):

Without foreign key, EF will not load the ProductType object.

You will need to do a new query. Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = ctx.Produts;

foreach (var product in products )
{
   ProductType type = (from t in ctx.ProductType where t.ProductTypeId == product.ProductTypeId select t).Single();    
   product.ProductType = type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this so I mocked up a quick test, which I ran both with and then without the foreign key in the database.  The answer seems to be yes, it will work, provided you have configured your keys still in Entity Framework.  Note however, of course, that the database will obviously not enforce reference constraints without the keys, although it looks like EF will.

Comment: did you use code first or EDMX? if using code first how did you configure the keys and not have it update the database? As for the database not enforcing the reference constraints is the purpose of removing them in my case

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that I was using Code First, but with migrations disabled.  I configured the keys with the fluent api, but I think data annotations would work as well.  If you have migrations enabled, that may be problematic.